# hooking a function using a debugger

Tags: debugging, hook, reverse-engineering, windbg, frida

I currently got into reverse engineering and now I am trying to solve different CrackMes. At the moment I hook functions with Frida and it's JavaScript API. I understand the theory behind hooking a function. Now I have read an article about "soft function hooking" where one is using a debugger (like WinDBG etc.). I am not very familiar with working with a debugger but I would like to learn it.

Could someone explain me how you can hook a function with a debugger?

- what exactly are the steps involved? - Do I have to set a breakpoint in the program, stop its execution and then manipulate the first 5 bytes of a function, before letting it run again?

Comment: Basically... yes, I'd say. Jump somewhere else, perhaps memory allocated with `.dvalloc` and then jump back. Note that there is https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ where the RE experts are - but you might not be very welcome with such a beginner question. You'd probably better given an example of how you hooked it (MRE) with the tools you know and have and then ask whether there's a simpler way.

Comment: "Soft hooking" usually refers  to logging or or modifying function arguments without code modification (e.g. using a redirection / trampoline to somewhere else). There's a good exemple with [windbg and pykd here](https://webstersprodigy.net/2014/01/06/soft-function-hooking-with-windbg-and-pykd/).